# Full Text Search :SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, installation, full-text-search, features

I want to enable full text search in sql server the feature already checked in the installation but in sql when i make this query

```
select serverproperty('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

The value 0 should be 1 ? How i can fix this issue?

from SQL server configuration manager it's Running ,
checked[image]

and from installation it's 
[image]

Check if i[image] have enough permissions to run these procedures.

Comment: please no pictures with scripts, rather, post the script itself

Answer (score 1):

You said that you have [already installed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6511671/1501497) the feature,
but when you look at the sql server configuration manager do you see it there?

[image]

according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/fulltextserviceproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

IsFulltextInstalled The full-text component is installed with the current instance of SQL Server.

0 = Full-text is not installed.

1 = Full-text is installed.

NULL = Invalid input, or error.

Here you can find a detailed way to [install Full Text on SQL Server 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12531369/1501497):

Directions:

1. Open the Programs and Features control panel.
2. Select Microsoft SQL Server 2012 and click Change.
3. When prompted to Add/Repair/Remove, select Add.
4. Advance through the wizard until the Feature Selection screen. Then select Full-Text Search.

[image: Step 1] 
[image: Step 2]

[image]

5. On the Installation Type screen, select the appropriate SQL Server instance.
6. Advance through the rest of the wizard.

Source (with screenshots): http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/adding-sql-full-text-search-to-an-existing-sql-server/5546

This link is also a GREAT article, but a bit more comprehensive:

[Step-by-Step: Enabling Semantic Search on SQL Server 2012](https://blog.aelterman.com/2012/04/14/step-by-step-enabling-semantic-search-on-sql-server-2012/)

> Semantic Search is a powerful new addition to SQL Server 2012.
>   Semantic Search builds upon the full-text index feature and adds the
>   ability for SQL Server to determine key words in documents. Uses can
>   include analysis of text to determine similarity between two
>   documents, extract key words from documents, or find documents that
>   contain key words.
>
> Step-by-step, enabling Semantic Search on a column in SQL Server 2012
>   involves:

1.Install the Full-Text and Semantic Extractions for Search feature

2.Install the Microsoft Office 2010 Filter Packs and Service Pack 1

3.Install, attach and register the semantic language database

4.Create a full-text catalog

5.Create a full-text index with the Statistical_Semantics option enabled

Please visit [this link for more details](https://blog.aelterman.com/2012/04/14/step-by-step-enabling-semantic-search-on-sql-server-2012/) on the above instructions. There are pictures and more detailed info you can find there.

If you have this error message:

> Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be
>   loaded

when you run these procedures below:

```
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1; 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages'; 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';
```

Then:

[Check up what you find in the files below](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/view-and-read-sql-server-setup-log-files?view=sql-server-ver15):

File    Path
Summary.txt   %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log

Summary__Date.txt  %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_hhmmss

Detail.txt  %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup 
Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_hhmmss

Datastore   %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_hhmmss\Datastore

MSI Log Files   %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup 
Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_hhmmss\.log

ConfigurationFile.ini   %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_hhmmss

SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm %programfiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\nnn\Setup Bootstrap\Log\YYYYMMDD_hhmmss

For unattended installations    %temp%\sqlsetup*.log

and also check [sql server error log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10366/22336)

Based on the information you get from the logs, you might need to deal with it accordingly, hopefully avoiding having to reinstall anything.

If you see this error message:

> The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not
>   have permission to use it.

Check if you have enough permissions to run these procedures.

[In regards to permissions the minimum requirement is](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-fts-active-catalogs-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions):

> On SQL Server, requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission. On SQL Database
>   Premium Tiers, requires the VIEW DATABASE STATE permission in the
>   database. On SQL Database Standard and Basic Tiers, requires the
>   Server admin or an Azure Active Directory admin account.

Comment: please check the Q ,  i edited it .

Comment: please check the links on the answer, after getting it installed, create a catalog as described, can you do that? If not, what are the causes?

Comment: when i follow as catalog 
EXEC sp_fulltext_service @action='load_os_resources', @value=1;
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'update_languages';
EXEC sp_fulltext_service 'restart_all_fdhosts';

i got this error :Full-Text Search is not installed, or a full-text component cannot be loaded.

Comment: The specified schema name "sys" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it.

Comment: check the minimal permission on the answer

Comment: i check it , but empty result